# Js code working in customize Theme in wordpress but not working in website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, customization

i have try put some HTML code in my website but when i use js code , it's working in wp customize theme but when i loading the page it doesn't work!

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: Any errors in the [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)?